# How to change UILabel text-color when i expand and Collapse the TableList cells in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to iOS and I have created one Expandable-ListView and here my main requirement is when I expand the cell then I want change `UILabel` textcolor as a "RED" color and remaining all cells `UILabel` textcolors must be "ORANGE" like my below image and when I collapsed the expanded cell then that cell's `UILabel` textcolor must be "ORANGE."

For this I have tried below code but when i collapse cell textcolor is not changing like "ORANGE" please help me.

### My code:

### .h file:-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray  *arrayForBool;
    NSArray *sectionTitleArray;

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *expandableTableView;

@end
```

### .m file:-

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    UILabel *viewLabel;
    BOOL collapsed;
    NSInteger collapsedSection;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self initialization];
}

#pragma  mark - Initialization

-(void)initialization
{
    arrayForBool=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    sectionTitleArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                       @"Apple",
                       @"Strawberry",
                       @"Grapes",
                       @"Orange",
                       @"Banana",
                       @"Papaya",
                       @"Guava",
                       @"pineapple",
                       nil];

    for (int i=0; i<[sectionTitleArray count]; i++) {
        [arrayForBool addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark TableView DataSource and Delegate Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if ([[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:section] boolValue]) {
        return section+2;
    }
    else
    return 0;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *cellid=@"hello";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellid];
    }
        BOOL manyCells  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];

             /********** If the section supposed to be closed *******************/
        if(!manyCells)
        {
            cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

            cell.textLabel.text=@"";
        }
             /********** If the section supposed to be Opened *******************/
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d",[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section],indexPath.row+1];
            cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
            cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"point.png"];
            cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone ;
        }
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

                  /********** Add a custom Separator with cell *******************/
    UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 40, _expandableTableView.frame.size.width-15, 1)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [sectionTitleArray count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    /*************** Close the section, once the data is selected ***********************************/
    [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

     [_expandableTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue]) {
        return 40;
    }
    return 0;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 40;
}

#pragma mark - Creating View for TableView Section

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UIView *sectionView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280,40)];
    sectionView.tag=section;

    for (id subview in sectionView.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        } else if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    viewLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, _expandableTableView.frame.size.width-10, 40)];
    viewLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    viewLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"List of %@",[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:section]];
    [sectionView addSubview:viewLabel];

    if (collapsedSection ==  section) {

        viewLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }else{

        viewLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }

    /********** Add a custom Separator with Section view *******************/

    UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 40, _expandableTableView.frame.size.width-15, 1)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [sectionView addSubview:separatorLineView];

    /********** Add UITapGestureRecognizer to SectionView   **************/

    UITapGestureRecognizer  *headerTapped   = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];
    [sectionView addGestureRecognizer:headerTapped];

    return  sectionView;
}
#pragma mark - Table header gesture tapped

- (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{


    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];

    collapsedSection = gestureRecognizer.view.tag;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

       collapsed  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];

        for (int i=0; i<[sectionTitleArray count]; i++) {

            if (indexPath.section==i) {

                [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!collapsed]];
            }
        }

        [_expandableTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:gestureRecognizer.view.tag] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: are you trying to change color of **Apple 1** text ? @Krish

Comment: no @jay Bhalani Header color(like above List of Apple,List of Strawberry) i want to change color as "RED" when cell is expand and when cell collapse then color must be "ORANGE"

Comment: i hope your understand my requirement

Comment: its purely depends on , how you implemented.

Comment: i have already tried above code but when i collapse expanded cell then header label color not changing like "ORANGE" please help me

Comment: my requirement is vey clear that is expanded cells header label textcolors colors must "RED" and collapsed cells Header textcolors must be "ORANGE"

Comment: Are you getting proper indexpath when tap on section?

Comment: yes i am getting but i am not understand why result is not coming

Comment: @Krish share your .h .m file code

Comment: so your problem in when you collapsed the cell? expand is working perfect with red text? Am i right or wrong.

Comment: yes exactly when i collapsed the cell then Header label textcolor is not changing and expand is working perfect

Comment: hi @imran i have posted my .h and .m files is that ok?

Comment: Make collapsedSection value nil if it is already expand and you want to collapse that section

Comment: please explain me with some code i am very new for ios

Comment: collapsedSection = gestureRecognizer.view.tag; replace this code with  if(gestureRecognizer.view.tag == collapsedSection){  collapsedSection = nil  } else {  collapsedSection = gestureRecognizer.view.tag;    IN YOUR SECTION TAP METHOD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97831/discussion-between-krish-and-jaimish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just you have to replace the following line :

```
if(collapsedSection ==  section)
```

with

```
if ([[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:section] boolValue])
```